# Send EditText Data from One Activity to Another

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

How should I get the text entered in an edittext and send that data to a different activity?

Example:
If a user enters text in an EditText, and presses a submit button, I want to store the text entered in the EditText and show it in a different activity when that activity is active.

Comment: *"I want to store the text entered in edittext and show it later in listview."* So do exactly that. What's the problem? You know how to get the text from a text input, you know how to store things in variables, you know how to show things in list views, what exactly are you missing?

Comment: Right. So get the input, store it, and then show it in a listview.

Comment: The problem is, I think, is that you mean not a different layout, but specifically, getting it to another "activity" .. see the answer below by Daniel

Comment: Please read [Starting Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: Please break your problem into small, solvable parts. Currently your question is too broad. You want to start another Activity, then you want to pass the value of EditText to that activity, and in the end you want to show the value in a ListView. All these things are already there on stackoverflow and internet. Just break it down and Google. I guess you're overwhelming yourself here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the info from `EditText`, with: `getText()`
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

2.Two ways you can send the data.

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("CONSTANT_NAME", EditText.getText);

//Add the bundle to the intent
browserIntent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(browserIntent);
```

In the other activity you should use:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String value = bundle.getString("CONSTANT_NAME");        

if (bundle.containsKey(MainActivity.CONSTANT_NAME))    {
    ....
}
```

Comment: CONSTANT_NAME is the name you assigned to the key you used in the other activity! That is exactly why I used the same word in the example.